# AJAX Upload and Sort like Drupal

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-files

I'm developing for Drupal, and I need a script from the Internet that is similar to the FileField module (http://drupal.org/project/filefield/).

This FileField module can be attached to a node, and it enables the user to upload files via AJAX. There are a litany of free AJAX uploaders on the web, but I need one that can also replicate FileField's sorting ability. Once a file has been uploaded via FileField, you have the ability to drag and drop images/files in a particular order and then save the node.

My goal is for my users to upload their images, and be able to move the images around in a particular order using drag and drop. The images will be displayed in a 'portfolio' like display, so the order of the images is important.

If you're wondering why I don't just use FileField, it's because the page I am wanting to implement this on is not technically a node.

Does anyone have a good link for a script that does this?

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7? In D7 there is an entity API which means that in theory you can have fields (like filefields) attached to other things than just nodes. Why is it not a node? Can you reconfigure to make it a node? It will be a lot easier.

Comment: you should probably elaborate on "not technically a node". Either it is a node or it isn't.